# Issue With JQuery Slider Conflicts

Tags: jquery, slider, conflict

I'm having an issue with JQuery conflicts on a slider I'm using but can't for the life of me figure out where it's happening.

I can see in the chrome console there's an error on line 1689

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'royalSlider'
```

I'm really not great with this sort of thing so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The slider displays fine on all other pages on the site, it's only the homepage the conflict appears to occur.

The problematic site is dev.agriland.ie and you'll see there's a section titled "RoyalSlider Issue" just under the main slider

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

JQuery scripts weren't being called on the page for some reason, had to manually insert them